# $f$ holomorphic function on an open set with finite number of zero, then $f=pg$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on an open set $G$, such that $f$ has a finite number of zeros, then we can write $f$ as $f = p*g$, where $p$ is a Polynom and $g$ a holomorphic function on $G$ without zeros.

I´ve tried using the contradiction and Liouville´s theorem, but not sure if that is the right way.

**Edit:**

So my new solution is this but I´m still not sure if it´s right

Let $(z_{1},z_{2},z_{3},...,z_{n}), n\in\mathbb{N}$ be the set of zeros of $f$, then we define:
$$ p(z) =\prod_{j=1:n}(z-z_{n})$$
which obviously has the same zeros as $f$. Then $f/p$ has no zeros, because they both have zeros at the same points. Then we can define $$g : = f/p$$ and $g$ ish holomophic, because $f$ and $g$ are also.

Comment: You don't need Liouville here, it is much simpler. First define $p$ as a polynomial with the same zeros as $f$. Then define $g = f/p$.

Comment: Then I should define $p$ as $\prod_{j=1:n}(z-z_{n})$ where $(z_{1},...,z_{n})$ are zereos of f, and then $f/p$ as $g$ or?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: But I come across a problem when I have to show that $f/p$, i.e. $g$, holomorphic, because for zeros of $f, g$, $f/g$ is undefined or?

Comment: $f $ is analytic, $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ is analytic at $0$, you know its value at $0$ by continuity

Comment: I edited my post with a solution based on all comments, care to check it and see if it´s right?